# Preferred approach for creating a new array based on mysql results

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a new array which stores order_status as the key, and count as the value. Now I have two approaches.

Which approach is the preferred one?

Approach #1

```
$ordersStatus = array();
$count = array();
while ($row = my_db_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $ordersStatus[] = $row['orders_status'];
        $count[] = $row['count'];
}
$orders_status_count = array_combine($ordersStatus, $count);
```

Approach #2

```
while ($row = my_db_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $orders_status_count[$row['orders_status']] = $row['count'];
}
```

Comment: Well you can use both, but I would probably go for the second one, since it is more readable and a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is preferable because maintaining the `key => value` integrity preserves the original association of the data, which you would eventually need to get back anyway if you used 2 separate arrays as in the first approach!

Also, the loop should be:

```
while ($row = my_db_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $orders_status_count[$row['orders_status']] = $row['count'];
}
```

Comment: Clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks! My projects / coding experiences always nudged me in this direction, so glad I could share

Comment: The projects I worked for braught me to the Italian restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use second approach with following modification.

```
   // if same status accrued then data will not overwrite ... 
    while ($row = my_db_fetch_array($sql)) {
       $orders_status_count[$r['orders_status']][] = $r['count'];
    }
```

Comment: No, thats not correct. That would make the array multidimensional.

Comment: if same status comes twice then it will overwrite on old value of array in single dimension..

Comment: So you are saying `[ ]` won't append items to the array?